# parse.com + backbone retrieve nested set of objects for a user

Tags: parsing, backbone.js, nested-datalist

I'd like to extend [this example](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users-associations)  that parse.com gives in its tutorials to work with backbone collections and a second level of data (comments).  Right now the exmaple is retrieving a list of posts for a user, with the following data structure:

```
USER
--------------------------------------
| User_ID |  Username | ......
--------------------------------------
| 1       |  John     | ........
| 2       |  Jane     | ........


POST 
--------------------------------------
| POST_ID  |  User_ID | Title    | .....
--------------------------------------
| 20       |  1       | abcdefg  | .....
| 21       |  1       | svsvdsv  | .....
```

I'd to extend this call to also return corresponding comments to each post.  Meaning there would be **one** api call to parse that returns all the posts and all the comments to those posts (properly nested) for the logged in user.  Below is an example of a comment data structure:

```
COMMENT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| COMMENT_ID  |  POST_ID  |  Comment_Text        | Title    | .....
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 30          |  21       |  awesome post woohoo | abcdefg  | .....
| 31          |  21       |  terrible post....   | svsvdsv  | .....
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.js not support nested models so you can use Backbone-relational.js for nested models,

Backbone-relational.js provides one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-one relations between models for Backbone
 [Backbone Relation](http://backbonerelational.org/)

classes

```
User = Backbone.Relational.Model({
    defaults : {
        id : '',
        name : '',
        posts : [], //collection
    },
    relation : [{
        type : 'HasMany',
        key : 'posts',
        relatedModel : 'com.dw.attendance.model.Post',
        reverseRelation : {
            key : 'user'
        }
    }]
});

Post = Backbone.Relational.Model({
    defaults : {
        id : '',
        user : '', //model
        comments : '', //collection
        title : '',
    },
    relation : [{
        type : 'HasOne',
        key : 'user',
        relatedModel : 'com.dw.attendance.model.User',
        reverseRelation : {
            key : 'posts'
        }
    },{
        type : 'HasMany',
        key : 'comments',
        relatedModel : 'com.dw.attendance.model.Comment',
        reverseRelation : {
            key : 'post'
        }
    }]
});


Comment = Backbone.Relational.Model({
    defaults : {
        id : '',
        post : '',//model
        text : '',
        title : ''
    },
    relation : [{
        type : 'HasOne',
        key : 'post',
        relatedModel : 'com.dw.attendance.model.Post',
        reverseRelation : {
            key : 'comments'
        }
    }]
});
```

your data like this, for user : `{id : 1, name : 'john', posts : [1,2,3]};`

then you can get, comments of any user post by,

```
user.get('posts').get('post_ID').get('comments');
```